# Handle event on disabled Node

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

Is there any way to handle, mouse click, for example on disabled element? My task is to have disabled list and make it enabled after double click on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A disabled Node does not receive mouse or key events.

See the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#disabledProperty).

You could wrap the node into another node and handle the mouse events there in case the child node is disabled.

Comment: Thanks Roland! I've missed this note in documentation, thought that there is some native solution. In that case I'll enable it with some additional button pressing.

Comment: Smart. Thanks for this strategy! I was just struggling with this writing my first JavaFX app and this is exactly the solution I need. Now I don't have to struggle with styles instead.