# Button EventHandler in Controller class is not working

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Hello I have two problems.

First one:
When I start my app, I can press my `ToggleButton` with spacebar.

Second one:
(Even without `ToggleButton`) My `EventHandler` on my button is not working, on pressing spacebar nothing is going on.

Main class:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {

        Parent parent = (Parent) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/MainView.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(parent);
        scene.getRoot().setFocusTraversable(true);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Login Page");
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Fxml file:

```xml
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="501.0" prefWidth="597.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.MainController">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="button" layoutX="136.0" layoutY="184.0" mnemonicParsing="false"  prefHeight="133.0" prefWidth="127.0" text="Button" />
      <Label fx:id="label" layoutX="199.0" layoutY="106.0" prefHeight="61.0" prefWidth="198.0" text="Label" />
      <ToggleButton fx:id="toggleButton" layoutX="318.0" layoutY="186.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="133.0" prefWidth="127.0" text="ToggleButton" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Controller class:

```
public class MainController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private Button button;
    @FXML
    private Label label;
    @FXML
    private ToggleButton toggleButton;
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        button.setDisable(true);
        button.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE) {
                    System.out.println("space pressed");
                    button.setDisable(false);
                }
            }
        });
        button.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE) {
                    System.out.println("space pressed");
                    button.setDisable(true);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the whole `fxml`

Comment: `toggleButton` is never assigned an an event handler.

Comment: Not sure what your problem with the `ToggleButton` being activated is, but there are some event handlers in place by default that allow you to interact with controls. One example would be mouse event handlers that trigger the `onAction` event on mouse click, but a focused button can also be activated via keys (enter works too). Since we only allow a single question per question and the first one is unclear, I closed this one as a dupe for covering the second half of the question.

Answer (score 0):

At first as **@c0der** mentioned you hasn't been assined event handler

as the `button` is disabled via `button.setDisabled(true)` so it can't receive any events such as mouse and key events see [that javafx doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#disabledProperty)

**Edit** with some search i found another similar question in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30341840/handle-event-on-disabled-node)